# NodeJS: load html with res.write()

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm new to Node so I'm trying to learn it. I'm trying to load a simple HTML file in Node but that gives me an error as HTML is not defined when I use `res.write(html)` I saw some examples where are similar to me so I would like to understand what is wrong here. 
I wrote this:

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;

fs.readFile('./index.html', (err, html) => {
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }
});

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.setHeader('Content-type', 'text/html');
    res.write(html);    
    res.end();
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
    console.log('Server started on port ' + port);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

As Soren pointed out, `html`is not defined when you call to `res.write()`. Asynchronous can be very convenient but it's a bit difficult to understand when you are a beginner. The best for you is to try to handle the concept of asynchronous tasks. Until then, a solution to your problem would be to use the **synchronous** version of `fs.readFile`, `fs.readFileSync` (docs [here](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options)), and call it inside the `createServer` function.

Since `readFileSync` returns the read stuff synchronously, you could do:

```
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.setHeader('Content-type', 'text/html');
    var html = fs.readFileSync('./index.html');
    res.write(html);    
    res.end();
});
```

Another option, as I guess you were trying to make, is to initialize the `html` variable in the callback of `readFile`.

```
var html_g; //global html variable
fs.readFile('./index.html', (err, html) => {
    if(err){
        throw err;
    } else {
        html_g = html; //html_g = content_of_index_file;
});
```

But since this function is asynchrounous, the `createServer` function could be called before `html_g` was initialize, causing problems.

Comment: Would it not be better to move the createServer inside the callback from the readFile?  That way there are no sync operations and no global variable -- which both are considered bad in Javascript

Comment: Sorry for the delay, @Soren, and yes, you're right. As I said, the best option is to handle the concept of "asynchronous-y" and use the callbacks, but some months ago I was on OP situation and it's always uplifting to make your first experiments work, even if they are poorly programmed.But yes, your proporsal would be the best option, from a good practices point of view.

Answer (score 1):

Your problems is that `html` variable is not set in the scope that you are trying to use it.

Almost everything in javascript is async, and you need to handle and build your logic so that values that is returned from an async call can be used elsewhere in the program.

In your case the `readFile` is an async call that reads and returns the file -- unfortunately for you the callback where you receive the html has it's own scope, and is not available after you have completed the execution of that callback.

The canonical mandatory readthough of how to do that is found here: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

There are many good solutions on this problem, for example using structures of closure or promises as well as other solutions.

A direct solution is to combine the and make use of the callback structure -- like in your example to make the user of `html` variable happen within the scope of the callback from the `readFile`, like

```
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.setHeader('Content-type', 'text/html');
    fs.readFile('./index.html', (err, html) => {
        if(err)
           res.write("Error");    
        else
           res.write(html);    
        res.end();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;

fs.readFile('./index.html', (err, html) => {
    if(err){
        throw err;
    } else if(html){
    const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
       res.statusCode = 200;
       res.setHeader('Content-type', 'text/html');
       res.write(html);    
       res.end();
    });
}
});


server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
    console.log('Server started on port ' + port);
});
```